# Adjust height of QListWidget when window is resized

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I have based a settings dialog on the Qt config dialog example found here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-configdialog-example.html

I would like the `QListWidget` to fill the left of the window (except for the button bar at the bottom) regardless of the vertical size of the window.  In Delphi there was a simple property to set.  I can't find a similar thing in Qt.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

--- edit ---
The example I linked to has the same behaviour. My code is virtually a copy of that example.

Here is a screen shot showing the problem:

[image: screen shot of config dialog]

Comment: Please show the code you have trouble with. In Qt layout managers take care of such things easily.

Comment: Post your *.ui file content.

Comment: @BartoszKP my code is almost exactly the same as the eample I linked to. The example also has the same behaviour.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov The GUI is built in C++ code in the example and in my project. I'm not sure the *.ui file will add much to this question.

Comment: @MichaelVincent "almost" :) By the rules of SO, please post a complete and minimal example that demonstrates your problem *in your question*. We don't like nor have time to guess and follow countless links to find the problem. It is your role to demonstrate it clearly. If you don't want to put some effort into defining the issue, people are unlikely put any effort in helping you.

Comment: @BartoszKP  The example I linked to displays the same behaviour. The code is available easily from with QT-Creator ... a few clicks and you can have the example running and see the issue.  I do understand why you're asking for my code - my resistance is not laziness, but by pointing you to Qt supplied code it shows it is not an issue with my code. Thank you for your help. Kind regards, Mike

Comment: @MichaelVincent I'm simply pointing out that "a few clicks" is *against SO policy*. What if the link goes down (as it happened before, when Qt was taken over by another brand)? Your question will be useless for future visitors. And that's SO's aim - creating knowledge repository for everyone, not only people asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by removing `mainLayout->addStretch(1);` from [configdialog.cpp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-configdialog-configdialog-cpp.html). This line adds empty space that stretches instead of other content when extra space is available.